# OpenGL drawing Circle / Ellipse (filled in) without glBegin?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw an Ellipse using OpenGL and map a texture to it. I do not want to use glBegin(...) or glVertex4f as they are deprecated. I got the Ellipse to display with the texture but only when I use GL_LINE_LOOP. This does not allow me to fill in the Ellipse with a texture. I have attempted using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP in hopes that this will fill in the Ellipse but that doesn't seem to render anything.

```
void Ellipse::makeEllipse(float radiusX, float radiusY)
{
  for(int i=0; i < 360; i++)
  {
    float rad = i*DEG2RAD;
    ellipse_vertices[i] = vec4(cos(rad)*radiusX,
               sin(rad)*radiusY,0,1);
   }
}
.
.
.
glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, numEllipsisVertices);
```

I have tried to find solutions to this but there are only deprecated examples using GLBegin and glVertex.

Comment: Great thing about those deprecated examples?  You can generally pull them into the modern age by replacing the `glVertex()` calls with a `push_back()` into a `std::vector<>` of `glm::vec3`s.

Answer (score 1):

GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP is likely not the drawing mode you want to use for an ellipse. But GL_TRIANGLE_FAN should work rather nicely. I suggest you start the ellipse with a center vertex to ease the geometry:

```
void Ellipse::makeEllipse(float radiusX, float radiusY)
{
  ellipse_vertices[0] = vec4(0,0,0,1);
  for(int i=1; i < numEllipseVertices; i++)
  {
    float rad = i*DEG2RAD;
    ellipse_vertices[i] = vec4(cos(rad)*radiusX,
               sin(rad)*radiusY,0,1);
   }
}
.
.
.
glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, numEllipseVertices);
```

Small language hint: ["ellipsis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) ≠  ["ellipse"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)